# Where to find the man page for the Windows API?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am more experienced on the POSIX side and I am currently struggling with the Windows API.

I would like to find a single entry point for the documentation and I have yet not found the documentation for `<wincon.h>`. I also can't figure out how much of the standard headers (C99/C11) are available.

For exemple I can find [winreg.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/) but not [wincon.h](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincon) (Error 404). On the [RegDeleteKeyA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regdeletekeya) documentation I can see the `LSTATUS` type but it is not documented.

What is the method to navigate through this API? Where is entry-point?

I agree that my question is somehow unclear, but my point is that I am looking for an equivalent of the man pages on Linux, but for the Windows API. The format is not important, I just need a manual.

More concrete examples:

- Can I use `int32_t` on Windows? Where is it documented?
- What is the definition of `LSTATUS`?
- Where can I find some examples to read the registry using `winreg`?
  ...

Comment: There's a search button at the top right. It looks like LSTATUS isn't documented but you can look it up in the Windows headers. The important thing about the return value is that the possible codes are documented under "Return Value" in the page you linked, the type doesn't matter

Comment: googling the function name (with "winapi" if needed) is the fastest "entry point" in my experience :) this question covers LSTATUS, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547419/errors-in-windows-dword-getlasterror-vs-hresult-vs-lstatus

Comment: @M.M I also noticed `LSTATUS` is not available from the search box. I could indeed  look at the headers, but I have not installed Visual Studio yet :(

Comment: Not sure what you are asking about regarding C99/C11 headers. That is completely separate to the Windows API. A C11-conforming compiler will come with C11 standard headers, etc. `int32_t` is provided by the major compilers that I'm aware of; it's an optional type in C11 and implementation-defined whether it exists but I would expect it exists for all compilers that support WinAPI programming

Comment: @M.M Well, I am confused too. I know that GLIBC or POSIX include C99 headers plus extra headers. I am expecting to find a single entry point of all I can use on Windows, so something like Windows Library = C11 headers + Windows.h + ...

Comment: Windows API is completely separate from C standard library. `#include <windows.h>` gets you almost all of it

Comment: I agree, but the best documentation I found about `<windows.h>` is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows.h), I am expecting an equivalent on the Microsoft side...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entry point to Microsoft’s platform documentation is the [MSDN library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library). It is (relatively; see comments) comprehensive.

> - Can I use `int32_t` on Windows? Where is it documented?

`int32_t` is not a platform type, it’s defined by the C and C++ core language. It’s *probably* documented somewhere in the MSDN library but I wouldn’t look it up there (that said, this is where you’d look up [Microsoft C++ language extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/int8-int16-int32-int64?view=vs-2019)).

Comment: It is not defined neither by C or C++, but by the standard ISO/IEC which require a revision date and so `int32_t` was introduced with `ISO/IEC 9899:1999`. I could not find with which standard Windows is compliant to

Comment: @nowox “It is not defined neither by C or C++” — yes it is, you’re trying to split hairs but C *is* [defined by] ISO/IEC 9899:1999 in common parlance (and equivalent for C++). Your point about language compliance of the Microsoft compiler is valid, but this is in fact documented on the MSDN.

Comment: I looked at your MSDN library link but I could not find any information about `wincon.h` or `LSTATUS` :(

Comment: Do you have a link?

Comment: There is a search box at the top right of the page linked. Type in `LSTATUS` and `Enter` which returns lots of results to follow up.

Comment: @nowox [Language definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/languages-cpp?view=vs-2019), [`wincon.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference); `LSTATUS` I can’t find myself, I suspect the documentation might be missing.

Comment: @WeatherVane To be fair all these results are useless.

Comment: @nowox: As far as I know the MSVC compiler is not, and probably never will be, fully C99 compliant, let alone C11 compliant. C support has no priority for Microsoft (their own words).

Comment: Microsoft's documentation is sometimes incomplete or outdated. IMO, get the gist from the docs, but verify the details in the headers.

Answer (score 2):

Second question:

> What is the definition of `LSTATUS`?

Edit:

The Windows header file `WinReg.h` has this line

```
typedef __success(return==ERROR_SUCCESS) LONG LSTATUS;
```

---

A list of Windows type definitions can be found in [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types). The type `LSTATUS` is not listed. The nearest to be found is

> `LRESULT`
>
> Signed result of message processing.
>
> This type is declared in `WinDef.h` as follows:
>
> ```
>  typedef LONG_PTR LRESULT;
> ```

Comment: LRESULT might be nearest in terms of the name but it is not close in usage (nor basic type!).

Comment: @Anders that is because I originally thought I found `LSTATUS` as a documented type and when I noticed my mistake I edited the answer and searched for `LSTATUS` definition.